# InstallShield 2015 LE makes Visual Studio 2012 crash

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-2015

I have installed InstallShield 2015 LE, and now my Visual Studio 2012 crashes when trying to add new project.
Is this happening because of incompatibility of versions? How can I solve this situation?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you running? Did you check  the logs? It is known that Installshield LE is sensitive to the VS editions.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012. I just made the Update4, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some research, I found out that after installing the InstallShield2015LE, opening a new project gets stucked and the application is shows "not responding" status. I had to wait for 10 minutes, untill the plug in was completely installed, and Visual Studio was working again normally. This happens only the first time you open visual studio after the installation.